# API request contract from URI

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to use data contracts for API request data and responses. So I created records for every request and response. The integration works fine except for `HttpGet` because Asp.Net by default tries to get complex data types from the body which is not allowed for REST GET.

The `FromUriAttribute` does not solve the problem. When I try to call the endpoint using Swagger or just Chrome I get the error `localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` so the endpoint is not even mapped correctly and not called at all.

So how do I get complex datatypes with no hierarchy (so no complex but only primitive members) from URIs

What I don't want to do:

1. Pass members of the contract as multiple parameters to the controller
2. Get using POST so I can use the request body

**EDIT:**

GetGpsTrackingPointsRequest.cs:

```
public record GetGpsTrackingPointsRequest(string? UserIdentifier, DateTime? MinTimeStampTracked);
```

GpsTrackingController.cs:

```
[ApiController]
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("api/v1/gps-tracking")]
public class GpsTrackingController : ControllerBase {
    private readonly ILogger<GpsTrackingController> _logger;
    private readonly IGpsTrackingService _gpsTrackingService;
    
    public GpsTrackingController(ILogger<GpsTrackingController> logger, IGpsTrackingService gpsTrackingService) {
        this._logger = logger;
        this._gpsTrackingService = gpsTrackingService;
    }
    
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public GetGpsTrackingPointsResponse Test([FromUri] GetGpsTrackingPointsRequest request) {
        return new GetGpsTrackingPointsResponse(false, Enumerable.Empty<GpsTrackingPoint>(), Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new[] {GetGpsTrackingPointsResponse.Error.InternalError});
    }
```

**What I don't want to do:**

Pass members of the contract as multiple parameters to the

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet]
public GetGpsTrackingPointsResponse Test([FromUri] string? UserIdentifier, [FromUri] DateTime? MinTimeStampTracked) {   
    return new GetGpsTrackingPointsResponse(false, Enumerable.Empty<GpsTrackingPoint>(), Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new[] {GetGpsTrackingPointsResponse.Error.InternalError});
}
```

Get using POST so I can use the request body

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPost]
public GetGpsTrackingPointsResponse Test(GetGpsTrackingPointsRequest request) { 
    return new GetGpsTrackingPointsResponse(false, Enumerable.Empty<GpsTrackingPoint>(), Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new[] {GetGpsTrackingPointsResponse.Error.InternalError});
}
```

Comment: Could you include some code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Your options for passing data through a GET request include query string, route parameters, headers and cookies. I'm not sure what the issue is since you haven't shown your implementation but I guess [FromRoute] might be useful if for some reason you are averse to query string

Comment: I'm not against query strings. I just cannot make it work, that multiple query strings are mapped into a single data contract model which is passed as a parameter to the controller endpoint and I don't want to specify the parameters one by one. I'll put some code to clarify.

Comment: You could serialize your object, like in base64url encoding, then pass it as one parameter

Comment: The problem could be your request type. The documentation says "A complex type must have a public default constructor and public writable properties to bind." Your record type doesn't meet those criteria. Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#complex-types

Comment: I had a chance to try it out and it worked fine for me using a record with the `FromQuery` attribute.